# What is the best way to handle Android ViewModels in navigation graph scope with a Fragment shared across multiple sub-graphs?

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewmodel, android-navigation

It is reasonable that a Fragment might be used from several sub-graphs in the navigation hierarchy. In this case if the fragment depends on a view model provided by the parent Fragment the view model needs to be in a sub-graph scope that changes depending on its parent.

Kotlin provides a convenient way to get a graph scoped view model:

```
    private val fvm: SoftenerViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.navigation_graph_softener)
```

but this hard codes in the sub-graph id.

What is the best way to address this case?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the following, but given that the new extension function is not already in the library it raises the question if there is a better way?

By direct analogy with the Kotlin supplied extension function define the following extension:

```
/**
 * Derived from [androidx.navigation.navGraphViewModels]
 */
@MainThread
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.navGraphViewModels(
    viewModelArgKey: String,
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM> {
    val backStackEntry by lazy {
        val id = arguments?.getInt(viewModelArgKey, 0)?:0
        require(id != 0) {"Fragment argument $viewModelArgKey required."}
        findNavController().getBackStackEntry(id)
    }
    val storeProducer: () -> ViewModelStore = {
        backStackEntry.viewModelStore
    }
    return createViewModelLazy(VM::class, storeProducer, {
        factoryProducer?.invoke() ?: backStackEntry.defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    })
}
```

This differs only in that the argument is a String, and the name of the argument is what needs to be given. The laziness ensures that the fragment arguments are referenced at the right time.

It is used just like the existing androidx library extension:

```
    private val fvm: SoftenerViewModel by navGraphViewModels("view_model_id")
```

The only requirement is the navigation sub-graph defines the argument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com...HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"
        />


    <navigation
        android:id="@+id/navigation_graph_softener"
        android:label="Softener"
        app:startDestination="@id/navigation_softener"
        >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_softener"
            android:name="com.hanafey.android.waterstats.ui.softener.SoftenerFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_softener"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_softener"
            />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_softener_history"
            android:name="com...SoftenerHistoryFragment"
            android:label="Softener History"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_softener_history"
            >
            <argument
                android:name="view_model_id"
                app:argType="reference"
                android:defaultValue="@id/navigation_graph_softener"
                />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```